# how to break single line to multiple lines

Tags: python

Create a test file with a single sentence of 20 words. Read the file, then insert carriage-return characters (\n) and write the test to a new text file that will be composed of four lines of five words.

This is what i have so far

```
my_file = open("twentywords.txt", "r")
temp_file = open("newfile.text", "w")

i = 1
for words in my_file:
    if i%5 == 0:
        print(words, file = temp_file)
    i = i + 1
```

We have not learned complex tools yet so keep it simple Stew

Answer (score 0):

Use `.split()` to make a list of words:

```
>>> 'This is a test'.split()
['This', 'is', 'a', 'test']
```

Calling `.split()` without an argument makes it split the string by all whitespace characters.

From there, you can use slices and `.join()`:

```
>>> '-'.join(['This', 'is', 'a', 'test'])
'This-is-a-test'
>>> ['This', 'is', 'a', 'test'][1:3]
['is', 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

Read in the entire file as a string.  Split the string using a space as a delimiter. Write the array elements to the output file.  At each fifth element insert a \n.

Comment: my_file = open("twentywords.txt", "r")
temp_file = open("newfile.txt", "w")

listme = my_file.readline()  I don't get how u mean to insert a \n
listme = listme.split(" ")
print(listme, file = temp_file)

Answer (score 0):

---

very unreadable, but oneliner:

```
mystring = my_file.read()
print "\n".join(([" ".join(line) for line in  zip(*(iter(mystring.split()),) * 5)]))
```